# necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $\phi$ and $\psi$ be two smooth functions on $\Omega$ open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. There exists a function $u=u(x,y)$ such that:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\phi(x,y)\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\psi(x,y)
\end{array}\right.$$
if and only if $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}$.

Where I can find the proof of this statement? Is it a obvious consecuence of some famous theorem (like implicit funtion)?

Many thank!

Comment: Yes, by the [symmetry of second derivatives aka. Schwarz' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives).

Comment: Thanks! It is clear that if $u$ is a solution, then $\partial_y \phi$ must be equal to $\partial_x\psi$. How can I prove the converse?

Comment: Integrate those terms again, and do some detail work with the integration constants.

Comment: @flawr weird..... I always cite that as clairaut's

Comment: @qbert I probably depends on where you are / what language it is used. Among german speakers it is widely known as *Satz von Schwarz*.

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is false in general, unless $\Omega$ is simply connected.

On the other hand, although you can give a more or less straightforward proof in this situation, it is a very particular case of the fact that the de Rham cohomology (which is a homotopy invariant) vanishes for contractible spaces together with Stokes' theorem.